# Google Calendar - Shared calendar event creator

Tags: google-calendar-api

currently I am using Google Calendar's XML feed for *shared* calendars to view when events are created and who created them. This works great, unfortunately, Google Calendar is getting rid of their XML feeds Nov 17, which is absurd but besides the point. Now I have a problem:

I have taken a look at the exported ICS file which tells me *when* an event was created but not the *creator* of the event, which is useless because there are 5 people sharing a calendar scheduling events and I need to know the author of the events. There is no specification for author in the ICS file (like there is with the author tag in the XML feed).

So the simple question is, with a shared calendar, is there a way to tell (without XML feeds) who created the event?

Thanks so much, Bob

Comment: If you have the calendar id, then you send request to acl.list(https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/list) to check rules imposed on this calendar. You can see who is the owner/reader for this calendar

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't my question. I want to know the author of the events on a shared calendar. Not the creator of the calendar. I am the owner/creator of all the calendars. Like I said, I am able currently through the XML feed to see when and who created events, but Google is removing XML feeds, so starting Nov 17 I will only be able to see when the event was created on the shared calendar through ICS file, but not who created the event. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Sorry, I understood in diff way. You can do events.get (for the event you want to know the details) and in the response, you will see creator,organizer and many details for that event. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful although slightly over my head. I've written a small php program that uses $xml = file_get_contents($url); to list events (and their authors) that were created within a specified date range on a shared calendar. Seeing how that $url will no longer be available, and I have essentially no google developers knowledge (aside from authing vtiger), could you point me in the right direction?